# Is it possible to create a dynamic mongoose query with a select form?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm curious if it's possible to display a "flowchart" of the data in my MongoDB database based on what I have done so far. I'm not sure if I'm going about it correctly. So basically each entry of the database is a "flow" for how a system works.

For example one entry is:

```
{"name" : "Dev3",
"region" : "HI",
"HC" : "Regional HCOT Instance",
"hcOrg" : "HINT",
"membership" : "M-SET",
"SBMO" : "KiSoft",
"kpOrg" : "HINT",
"IVR" : "NA",
"CPM" : "DSN3",
"__v" : 0 }
```

and the "flowchart" would look something like:

```
Dev3 -> HI -> Regional HCOT Instance -> HINT -> M-SET -> KiSoft -> HINT -> NA -> DSN3
```

and I want to have a select form that displays all the `name`, `region`, `HC`, `hcOrg`, etc. in my database where a user can pick and choose what to parameters they want and then when they click Submit, it displays the all the flowcharts that have those selections.

For example if someone selected `HI, CO, CA` under regions, it would display all the flowcharts that include those regions within the flow.

Is it possible to create a dynamic mongoose query with the form selections as the query, or is there another way to do this?

Comment: I'm not sure i understand you correctly, but it seems all you need is the standard Model.find() . For example : MyModel.find({ name: 'john', age: { $gte: 18 }});
Take a look here: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find

Comment: @i.brod actually yes...i just did some more research and came across the Model.find(). I'll try that, thanks!

Comment: So all you need to do is sent all parameters in the POST request body, and then:   Model.find(req.body)